# https server not starting, trying to start http and https simultaneously, http weirdly responding twice

Tags: node.js, http, https

[directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqMcp.jpg)

I am following a course, so what I am trying to  created two different server instances, one is http and another is https.

but I don't know https server isn't responding (ie browser show it can't access the page) but the http one is actually working.

and also sometime it weirdly responds to a request twice.. I don't know why.

[my code -- separated by lines](https://ide.codingblocks.com/s/45999)

output when I start the server

```
  uptime-monitoring-app >> NODE_ENV=production node app.js


HTTP Server @ 5000                      Environment : production
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

HTTPs Server @ 5001                     Environment : production

||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

when I hit the get request from the browser to  `localhost:5000/about`   it got two requests, I don't know why?

```
  uptime-monitoring-app >> NODE_ENV=production node app.js
...
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

notFoundHandler <<----- handled the request
Returning this response :  {}


aboutHandler <<----- handled the request
Returning this response :  {"name":"about handler"}
```

now if from the same page if I hit the `localhost:5000/`   it weirdly responding to 2 requests
now its calling the `aboutHandler` as well as the `notFoundHandler`  as well.

```
  uptime-monitoring-app >> NODE_ENV=production node app.js

...
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

notFoundHandler <<----- handled the request
Returning this response :  {}


aboutHandler <<----- handled the request
Returning this response :  {"name":"about handler"}


notFoundHandler <<----- handled the request
Returning this response :  {}


notFoundHandler <<----- handled the request
Returning this response :  {}
```

but if I got to  `localhost:50001/`  It shows error. the page can't be reached [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1wd9.jpg)
though there is no output on the terminal.. cursor is at the same point.

____________________ Update ____________________

I found this weird behaviour only in the browser, (safari) I don't see anything weird if I use postman. What is going on. please help

I think its a browser issue as the https api was hitting and actually generating the output, but it can be seen using postman. browser doesn't show error that the connection is not private.